# C# - Avoid Delay at Button Press/Spam

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I avoid that if I press a keyboard key, the key_Down event is triggered once, then there is a one-second delay and THEN it starts spamming the event?
I am using C# WinForms and this would be my code:

```
private void key_Down(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Key.A)
        {
            // Do Stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Thomas And how would I trigger the key_Down event from the Timer_tick event?

Comment: *What* do you want to avoid? The 1 second delay?

Comment: Wait... does the event continue to fire if you hold the key down? That cannot be right.

Comment: Do you want the listener to stop listening for 1 sec after first keydown event? Is this what you're asking?

Comment: The way I'm reading it is that he wants to avoid the 1 second delay before the event fires again. In which case the solution is to go to the keyboard configuration in windows, and adjust the repeat delay setting...

Comment: As I understand the question OP wants to mitigate against the effects of the keyboard repeat delay and repeat rate. @IanH.can you confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only respond to the event once then, by means of a flag, prevent the handler from "doing stuff" until a keyup is received. The keyup event would reset the flag.

So:

```
bool isAKeyDown = false;
private void key_Down(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Key.A && !isAKeyDown )
    {
        isAKeyDown = true;
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
private void key_Up(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Key.A)
    {
        isAKeyDown = false;
    }
}
```

This obviously only deals with a single key. You might choose to keep a bunch of flags, perhaps in a dictionary, to flag the state of many keys.

Because the handlers are called on the UI thread, you won't need to worry about synchronized access to variables that are referenced in the handlers.

Comment: I don't think it answers the question, i.e. "and THEN it starts spamming the event"

Comment: @ken2k : I think it does. I read the question as user wanting to mitigate against the effects of the keyboard repeat delay and repeat rate.

Comment: What's sure is that the question is not clear. I understood it as "_I want a first call to DoStuff, THEN a one second delay, THEN all other calls to DoStuff (i.e. "spamming")_". Well now it's up to the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can unsubscribe from event, and after 1sec subscribe back

```
 private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs)
    {
        this.KeyDown -= OnKeyDown;

        // Do Something

        Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(x => { this.KeyDown += OnKeyDown; });
    }
```

Comment: Nice, but even better would be to re-register the handler on keyup instead.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you hold down a key in notepad. There is a slight delay and then it adds lots of the character you are pressing.

You could use a different event...The keypress event might suit you better.

Comment: But I would want that _while_ the key is pressed an event is spammed.

Answer (score 0):

You could store a `DateTime` value for the first event, and compare it with the current time for each subsequent event:

```
private DateTime? dateFirstEvent;

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dateFirstEvent == null ||
        (this.dateFirstEvent != null && DateTime.Now.Subtract(this.dateFirstEvent.Value) > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
    {
        // Do stuff
        this.Text = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
    }

    if (this.dateFirstEvent == null)
    {
        this.dateFirstEvent = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Resets date
    this.dateFirstEvent = null;
}
```

No timer, no task, no new thread, very simple.